# What is this? UITableView with ContainerView which has child view controllers?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I need to know how is implemented Instagram's profile view controller.

As you can see in the picture, there is a segmented controller that let us choose between 2 different ways to display our photos. How do they do it?

The viewcontroller is a tableViewController and the collectionview is a cell on that table?

Or it is a simple viewcontroller with a scrollview that embeds that collectionview?

---

[image: Instagram profile]
<sub>(source: [mobile-patterns.com](http://img2.mobile-patterns.com/img/full/1380226689679-2013-09-25%2019.50.30.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do it. The one thing you could not do is make the parent view controller a `UITableViewController` that manages multiple views. A `UITableViewController` can only manage a table view and nothing else. However, it's perfectly ok to have a regular view controller manage a table view and other views as well. That's probably what I would do.

My guess is that the parent view controller is a custom parent view controller that acts like a tab bar controller (or maybe a tab bar controller with custom tabs). Then the view controller you're looking at is another custom view controller that manages a table view, one view of which displays a collection view.